# Product reference is undefiend

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema

I have a model named order. The order model is having a field name product which is a reference to the product model.
My Order model is like

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;
const ProductCartSchema = new Schema({
  product: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: Product,
  },
  name: String,
  count: Number,
  price: Number,
});

const orderSchema = new Schema(
  {
    products: [ProductCartSchema],
    transaction_id: {},
    amount: { type: Number },
    address: { type: String },
    updated: Date,
    user: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: User,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

var Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
var ProductCart = mongoose.model('ProductCart', ProductCartSchema);

module.exports = { Order, ProductCart };
```

And my product model schema is like

```
    var mongoose = require(mongoose);
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;
const productSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32,
      trim: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 2000,
      trim: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32,
      trim: true,
    },
    category: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: 'Category',
      required: true,
    },
    stock: {
      type: Number,
    },
    sold: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    photo: {
      type: Buffer,
      contentType: String,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

It's giving me error

> Product is not defined on order.js line no 7

Am I need to import product model in this if yes then how I can do that and if not then where is the error

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Product reference in your Order.js Schema, you need to import it.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;
var Product = require('Product'); <----------------------------------- Import this
const ProductCartSchema = new Schema({
  product: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: Product,
  },
  name: String,
  count: Number,
  price: Number,
});

const orderSchema = new Schema(
  {
    products: [ProductCartSchema],
    transaction_id: {},
    amount: { type: Number },
    address: { type: String },
    updated: Date,
    user: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: User,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

var Order = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema);
var ProductCart = mongoose.model('ProductCart', ProductCartSchema);

module.exports = { Order, ProductCart };
```

Comment: If we just require it like that then it will think that it's the library of node and even if I add ./ for the same directory because I have these two files in the same folder then it's giving me  throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Comment: I think the error is occurring due to this line. const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema; in your Product.js file remove that line. And in the place of "type: ObjectId" you can use "type: Schema.Types.ObjectId". The same case applies to order.js file too